# Does Data.Map work in a pass-by-value or pass-by-reference way? (Better explanation inside)

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I have a recursive function working within the scope of strictly defined interface, so I can't change the function signatures.

The code compiles fine, and even runs fines without error. My problem is that it's a large result set, so it's very hard to test if there is a semantic error.

My primary question is: In a sequence of function calls `A to B to A to B to breaking condition`, considering the same original Map is passed to all functions until breaking condition, and that some functions only return an Integer, would an insert on a Map in a function that only returns an Integer still be reflected once control is returned to the first function?

```
primaryFunc :: SuperType -> MyMap -> (Integer, MyMap)
primaryFunc (SubType1 a) mapInstance = do
    let returnInt = func1 a mapInstance
    (returnInt, mapInstance)
primaryFunc (SubType2 c) mapInstance = do
    let returnInt = primaryFunc_nonprefix_SuperType c mapInstance
    let returnSuperType = (Const returnInt)
    let returnTable = H.insert c returnSuperType mapInstance
    (returnInt, returnTable)
primaryFunc (ConstSubType d) mapInstance = do
    let returnInt = d
    (returnInt, mapInstance)

func1 :: SubType1 -> MyMap -> Integer    
func1 oe vt = do
    --do stuff with input and map data to get return int
    returnInt = primaryFunc
    returnInt

func2 :: SubType2 -> MyMap -> Integer
func2 pe vt = do
    --do stuff with input and map data to get return int
    returnInt = primaryFunc
    returnInt
```

Comment: What exactly is `MyMap`, and what is `SuperType` / `SubTypeₓ`? (Sounds suspicious at any rate: there are no subtypes in Haskell. Your code shouldn't even typecheck actually.)

Comment: Data SuperType = SubType1 sb1 | SubType2 sb2 deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

Comment: Why is this littered with do notation but not in a monad? I think you need to read up on some basic haskell, Have you looked at Learn You a Haskell for Great Good?

Comment: *Prima facie*, the answer would be "not", as `Data.Map.insert`, like pretty much everything in Haskell, will leave its arguments unchanged (while there are mutable references, you have to explicitly introduce them). It is not clear if there is something else going on in your code - as posted, it won't compile, given the `do` blocks without monad types.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, ugly Haskell, but upcoming deadlines :D

Comment: Haskell, great though it is for concise and quick-written code, is not a good language in which to hack together stuff whilst you don't really know how it works. Please use Perl or whatever dynamic language for that kind of purpose. Better though, try to avoid the deadline somehow, _learn the language properly_, and then get stuff done properly with idiomatic code. (The danger being that you will at some point spend ages figuring out the most beautiful, mathematically elegant and general way to do stuff you could have done much easier with more conventional tools.)

Comment: Your final paragraph, in which you define your primary question, is so dense and ambiguous that it is impossible to say precisely what you are asking.  For example, which is the *first* function?  The function that only returns an integer, or the function that calls it?

Comment: "(Better explanation inside)": false.

Comment: Ouch, that's harsh ;)

Comment: Don't get us wrong. We certainly do want to help people who struggle with learning Haskell. Actually the Haskell community prides itself of being particularly friendly... however, you should know that Haskell has something of an inofficial motto: _Avoid success at all cost_. People who are passionate about Haskell generally are really _passionate about the language_, and don't just value it as a tool like, e.g., C++ programmers do. So if you ask a Haskell question, don't expect answers like "standard guarantees that no extra object will be allocated, so this ugly fix should be fine".

Comment: Yeah, it's no problem, I was just teasing. Haskell looks novel, and I want to get more to get grips with its good practices, but I'm sure most of you will remember being an undergrad with 99 deadlines in an infinitesimally short time :) Sometimes beauty is sacrificed :D

Comment: All I meant is that your title does coherently express your question.  Which is more than your question does ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is almost impossibly dense and ambiguous, but it should be possible to answer what you term your "primary" question from the simplest first principles of Haskell:

- No Haskell function updates a value (e.g. a map).  At most it can return a modified *copy* of its input.
- Outside of the IO monad, no function can have side effects.  No function can affect the value of any variable assigned before it was called; all it can do is return a value.

So if you pass a map as a parameter to a function, nothing the function does can alter your existing reference to that value.  If you want an updated value, you can only get that from the *output* of a function to which you have passed the original value as input.  New value, new reference.

Because of this, you should have absolute clarity at any depth within your web of functions about which value you are working with.  Knowing this, you should be able to answer your own question.  Frankly, this is such a fundamental characteristic of Haskell that I am perplexed that you even need to ask.

If a function only returns an integer, then any operations you perform on any values made available to the function *can only* affect the output - that is, the integer value returned.  Nothing done within the function can affect anything else (short of causing the whole program to crash).

So if function A has a reference to a map and it passes this value to function B which returns an int, nothing function B does can affect A's copy of the map.  If function B were allowed to secretly alter A's copy of the map, that would be a side effect.  Side effects are not allowed.

You need to understand that Haskell does not have *variables* as you understand them.  It has immutable values, references to immutable values and functions (which take inputs and return new outputs).  Functions do not have *variables* which are *in scope* for other functions which might alter those variables on the fly.  That cannot happen.

As an aside, not only does the code you posted show that you do not understand the basics of Haskell syntax, the question you asked shows that you haven't understood the primary characteristics of Haskell as a language.  Not only are these fundamentals things which can be understood before having learned any syntax, they are things you *need* to know to make sense of the syntax.

If you have a deadline, meet it using a tool you do understand.  Then go learn Haskell properly.

Comment: > Outside of the IO monad, no function can have side effects.

But this is wrong. Any monadic function can have some side effects according to monad. 'Variables' could be modified in the State and ST monads as well.

Comment: @user2894391 No it's not. Monads are still side-effect free - with the exception of the IO monad of course.

Comment: @user2894391 What side effects does the Maybe monad have?  It either contains a value or Nothing.  If it contains a value, you can extract it.  Nothing which happens inside the Maybe monadic context can have side effects.  The IO monad has extra restrictions which means that no value generated within an IO monad can be extracted - except within another IO monad.  So side-effects are constrained within that box.

Comment: @Cubic IO is just the **ST** on **RealWorld**. **ST** is just a sort of **State** accelerated by builtins accessing actual volatile memory (but it is just a compiler optimization!). IO and ST can be fully simulated by pure code. The only magical thing here is the unsafePerformIO function. But **IO** just an ordinary monad! You will continue to say that "with the exception of the IO monad of course"?

Comment: There are no side effects with ST.  It allows updates in place (so, mutability) but only within the monad and only in a strict manner.  Nothing can leak and you cannot pass out a reference to a mutable object.  You will always get the same output for the same input. It is all referentially transparent.

Comment: @itsbruce So doesn't have IO. One can think of IO just as a pure monad producing source code in some imperative language. This code is always the same: so IO actually doesn't have any side effects! The only magical thing that actually has them is a function that executes this code, i.e. unsafePerformIO. But as the name suggests it breaks purity and can't be implemented in Haskell.

Comment: There is nothing imperative about the code in a monadic function. It *looks* imperative if you use **do** notation, but it isn't. Even in the IO monad, it is possible to discard a value so that an expression will never be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you will find that

> an insert on a Map in a function that only returns an Integer

is nearly impossible to express. Yes, you can technically do it like in

```
 insert k v map `seq` 42        -- force an insert and throw away the result
```

but if you think that, for example:

```
 let done = insert k v map in 42
```

does anything with the map, you're probably wrong.

In no case, however, is the original `map` altered.